# "Adding" risk-free asset to covariance matrix after the fact

Tags: covariance-matrix

Given a covariance matrix that was calculated from the returns of a number of risky assets.

Is there a way to "add" a risk-free asset to the covariance matrix without calculating its covariance with all the other assets? I thought about simply adding a column and row filled with zeros that seems wrong as there should be some correlation between risky and riskless assets.

Just wondering whether there are any shortcuts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a bunch of zeros, then your covariance matrix will be singular, which could lead to problems depending on what you're doing (anything that involves inverting a matrix will have problems).

If you have to have a covariance matrix that includes the risk-free rate, then you need to provide a variance for the risk-free rate (i.e. you're no longer strictly assuming it's risk-free) at a minimum. This is like assuming that you're investing in a short-term floating rate security (and you're implicitly making assumptions about the process of the rates). For instance, if you have a 6 month horizon, you could assume that there is no risk of default in any given month, but that the rate might re-set each month. You still aren't risking default, but you do have some interest rate risk.

If you are using a fixed term risk-free security, like a 1 month T-bill, and your fixed term matches your investment horizon, 1 month in this case, then it will have zero variance at the horizon. In this case, you probably shouldn't be using the risk-free rate in a covariance matrix. Separate out the decisions. This becomes a little bit trickier if you're trying to account for transactions (b/c you have to include both decisions in the optimization then).

If you have a longer horizon, then you can make assumptions about the dynamics of the risk-free rate, such as mean-reversion or its relationship to inflation.